# How to use node package preinstalled by VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, token, textmate

For example,

`npm install vscode-textmate`

requires dev tools to compile native C code. Since VSC already installed grammars for many languages as well as the node package precompiled for the current platform - is there a way to load the package already on disk along with the preinstalled language grammar?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do this. It would create an implicit dependency between your extension and VS Code's internal modules, which we don't guarantee will be the expected version or even exist.

See [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/658) for pointers on native modules in extensions

Comment: Concern is understandable but currently there is no good way to get colorization/tokenization information via public API. And generally specking, extension always depends on the host and host can make breaking changes. I'd say it is up to the extension author to deal with this.